# Is it possible to use Spotify Web without WebSockets?

Tags: spotify

The [Spotify Web Player](https://play.spotify.com/) doesn't appear to load if it cannot establish a WebSockets connect to the Spotify servers. The Chrome developer tools show me that, in my case, it's trying to establish a connection to `wss://lon2-linkap-a4.ap.spotify.com/`.

Does Spotify have a SWF-fallback like [rdio](http://www.rdio.com/)?

This is useful for environments where HTTP connections are possible but WebSockets are not.

Answer (score 1):

No there is no fallback and no alternative other than using trying to use their desktop client.

Spotify is likely trying to protect their music from being downloaded, and this is just one of those methods.

There should be no problem with using WebSockets in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Try using https://play.spotify.com/?http=1

I'm not exactly sure what it does, but it does help Spotify Web Player work behind a company proxy.

Comment: Worked for some weeks. Now this also ineffective.